# Leetcode 104 Maximum Depth of Binary Tree

Tags: javascript

I am reviewing the solution to this [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/) problem. The solution is the following:

```
var maxDepth = function(root) {
  let maxNode = (node, sum) => {
    if (node === null) {
      return sum;
    }
    return Math.max(maxNode(node.left, sum + 1), maxNode(node.right, sum + 1));
  }
  return maxNode(root, 0);  
};
```

I was wondering why `return maxNode(root, 0);` must include a `return`. Is it required to 'activate' the inner function? If so, why doesn't just `maxNode(root, 0)` just 'activate' it?

Comment: It'll be an infinite loop otherwise. A function calling itself for an infinite number of times. A return with conditions prevents it from running forever when that condition is met. Go read about recursive functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function `maxDepth` will determine the maximum depth of a binary tree.

You would use it like this:

```
let depth = maxDepth(treeRoot);
```

Without the `return`, the function will determine the depth but you will not get the result when you call the function.

Answer (score 1):

The solution includes "recursion", which means the `maxNode` function is called multiple times from within itself. This requires the `maxNode` function to return a value to it's calling "instance".
The `maxDepth` function has a return statement to return the calculated maxNode value.

Answer (score 0):

It is a another construction of a recursive function by taking a `sum` as parameter for a recursion.

It could be easily rewritten to the below function where the adding of one is outside of the function call.

```
var maxDepth = function(node) {
        if (!node) return 0;
        return 1 + Math.max(maxNode(node.left), maxNode(node.right));
    };
```